# The best practice on how to wait for data within thread and write it into file?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-2010

I am programming multi-threaded app. I have two threads. On is for transferring some data from device to global data buffer and second is for writing those data to file.

Data from device to buffer is transferring asynchronously. The purpose of second thread should be to wait for specified amount of data to be written in main data buffer and finally to write it to file.

Well the first thread is in DLL and second one is in main app. Temporarily I solve this with events. First thread transfers data from device to main data buffer and counts data and when specified amount of data is transferred it sets an event. The second one waits for event to be signalled and when it is it runs some code for data store. Simple as that it is working.

```
  Thread1.Execute:

  var DataCount, TransferedData: Integer;

  DataCounter := 0;
  while not Terminted do
  begin
    TransferData(@pData, TransferedData);
    Inc(DataCounter, TransferedData)
    if DataCounter >= DataCountToNotify then SetEvent(hDataCount);
  end;



  Thread2.Execute:

  hndlArr[0] := hDataCount;
  hndlArr[1] := hTerminateEvent;

  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    wRes := WaitForMultipleObjects(HandlesCount, Addr(hndlArr), false, 60000);
    case wRes of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        begin
          Synchronize(WriteBuffer);                   // call it from main thread
          ResetEvent(hndlArr[0]);
        end;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
        begin
          ResetEvent(hTerminateEvent);
          break;
        end;
      WAIT_TIMEOUT:  Break;
    end;
  end;
```

Now I would like to make second thread more independent... so I can make multiple instances of second thread and I don't need to wait for first thread. I would like to move data counting part of code from first thread to second one so I won't need data counting in first thread anymore. First one will be just for data transfer purpose.

I would like to use second one as data counter and to store data. But now I will have to loop and constantly check manually for specified data amount. If I had while loop I will have to add some sleep so second thread will not decrease computer performances but I don't know how long should sleep be while speed of data transfer in firts thread is not constant and thus speed of counting in second thread will vary.

My guess that this code sample is not good:

```
  Thread2.Execute:
  var DataCount: Integer;
  DataIdx1 := GetCurrentDataIdx; 
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin     
    if (GetCurrentDataIdx - DataIdx1) >= DataCountToNotify then 
    begin
      Synchronize(WriteBuffer);
      DataIdx1 := GetCurrentIdx;
    end;
    sleep(???);
  end;
```

So my question is what is the best approach to solve that issue with data counting and storing it within second thread? What are your experiences and suggestions?

Comment: Why do you force the writing of the file to the main thread, `Synchronize(WriteBuffer)`? I do not understand how you will manage to multiply the second thread and still maintain write order to a single file.

Comment: Thread will be multiplied but data will be stored to different files. I nowhere wrote I am going to write it to same file. My goal is to have multiple controls which are able to store data from same source to different files.

Comment: That's good to know, since the answer will depend on this information. Still I wonder why the file write must be enforced to the main thread.

Comment: @Nix - listen well to LU RD.  The file system is 100% thread-safe, no synchronization required.

Comment: Nix, also how will the first thread know how to distribute data to the receiver threads ? Normally such a producer thread just assembles the data and put it on a queue. Then as many consumer threads as needed can handle the draining of the queue.

Comment: Well I had some issues and I solved it with Synchronize(WriteBuffer). WriteBuffer is just method which writes some data into file. Buffers are allocated in exe and I just pass pointers to them in dll. For synchronizing threads I use mutexes. First thread is reading data from device to data buffer and I change some variables such as LastIndex which is integer number of last index in buffer of written data. So I expect I will have to check for LastIndex in second thread but I would like to avoid sleep. As I mentioned "sleep" solution is bad. I am looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some issues.  @LU RD has already pointed one out - don't synchronize stuff that does not need to be synchronized.  It's not clear what 'WriteBuffer' does, but the file system and all databases I have used are just fine to have one thread opening a file/table and writing to them.

Your buffer system could probably do with some attention.  Is there some 'specified data amount' or is this some notional figure that allows lazy writing?

Typically, producer and consumer threads exchange multiple buffer pointers on queues and so avoid sharing any single buffer.  Given that this is a DLL and so memory-management calls can be problematic, I would probably avoid them as well by creating a pool of buffers at startup to transfer data round the system.  I would use a buffer class rather than just pointers to memory, but it's not absolutely required, (just much more easy/flexible/safe).

Sleep() loops are a spectacularly bad way of communicating between threads.  Sleep() does hae its uses, but this is not one of them.  Delphi/Windows has plenty of synchronization mechanisms - events, semaphores, mutexes etc - tha make such polling unnecessary.

LU RD has also mentioned the problems of parallel processing of data whose order must be preserved.   This often requires yet another thread, a list-style collection and sequence-numbers.  I wouldn't try that until you have the inter-thread comms working well.

Comment: Upper code is just for demo purpose. Don't bother with Synchronize. I already have fixed things and I use proper mechanism for synhronizing threads etc. As I mentione I would like to count data and then when condition applies to eg. DataCountToNotify = 8192  I would like to store data. But I would like to avoid sleep. Is there any other alternative how to do that?

Comment: @Nix if I'm not mistaken, so long as your thread does "something" in the while loop, then you can skip the "sleep", but you can use sleep(1) which is a sleep of anywhere between 1 and 55 ms(win xp has an issue, not sure about future versions)

Comment: @DorinDuminica, see [thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program](https://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx) for arguments against using `Sleep` in a thread.

Comment: @LURD thank you for the link, it gives some very good info, however, sleep could be used in say reestablishing a connection or "waiting for X amount of data to be available in a place(table, file system, etc.)"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the `Sleep()` call in your second thread, use a waitable timer like `TSimpleEvent`.

Set the sleep time to handle all your timing conditions.
There is an advantage of using this scheme instead of a normal `Sleep()`, since a waitable timer will not put the thread into a deep sleep.

To dispose the thread, see comments in code.

```
var
  FEvent: TSimpleEvent;
  FSleepTime: Integer = 100;  // Short enough to handle all cases

Constructor TThread2.Create;
begin
  Inherited Create( False);
  FEvent := TSimpleEvent.Create;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TThread2.Execute;
var 
  DataCount: Integer;
begin
  DataIdx1 := GetCurrentDataIdx; 
  while (fEvent.WaitFor(FSleepTime) = wrTimeout) do
  begin
    if Terminated then
      break;
    // Do your work
    if (GetCurrentDataIdx - DataIdx1) >= DataCountToNotify then 
    begin
      // Write data to buffer
      DataIdx1 := GetCurrentIdx;
    end;
  end;
end;

// To stop the thread gracefully, call this instead of Terminate or override the DoTerminate
procedure TThread2.SetTerminateFlag;
begin
  FEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

Comment: LU RD thanks this looks very promising. I will have to vary FSleep time depending also on speed of data transfer in first thread. I can calculate that time. Like I said I try to avoid sleep in thread so that is why I was looking for a better alternative to sleep. I've never used sleep in any thread I programmed. I didn't find it very safe. I like system to be more determinated. Thanks a lot. I will try to realize it in a way you suggested.

Comment: This is reasonable on first look, but it's not.  Did you mean 'wrSignaled' instead of 'wrTimeout'?  Also, it's still got the Sycnhronize call in here that makes the thread worse than ineffective - it will actually introduce more delay.

Comment: @MartinJames, the Synchronize is evidently wrong, but the OP said this was not a problem anymore. The loop will continue to run while not signaled (every FSleepTime millisecond). This looks ok in my mind.

Comment: I just wanted to add that this solution might have one potential flaw: first iteration of thread will execute with a delay defined by `FSleepTime`. This can be avoided by changing loop from `while` to `repeat..until`.